# How do you create a new xbox avatar so that you have more than one?

Tags: xbox-360

I just purchased an XBOX with Kinect for my family and I was able to create an avatar for me but how do you create an Avatar for each of the members of the family?

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to create an account for each person that wants an avatar.

Answer (score 1):

on the tv(where you really play games) you go to social and press sign out. then keep going right and then you find a icon that says make a new avatar and then click and you are all set... you may do this as many times so you can make more avatars, i hope this helped! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create one with Kinect as long as it's on a separate account.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only get one avatar per account. Try logging out of your active account (you will need to re-enter your password when you log back in later). Once you've logged out, the Xbox should let you create an entirely new account with its own avatar. I suspect this means that the new account will not be able to access Xbox Live without a separate subscription. Hope this helps!